# FiddlerCore: HTTP Tunnel Issue

Tags: http, https, fiddler, tunnel, fiddlercore

I have an application, and I am trying to intercept its requests with FiddlerCore.

Using Fiddler, I see the requests as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhUqK.png

(HTTP CONNECT tunnel into HTTPS request)

When using FiddlerCore, I am only seeing the initial HTTP CONNECT tunnel, and the application is not requesting. after that, stating:

> Failed to connect to server.

This is the code I'm using in the BeforeRequest method:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT"))
    {
        oSession["x-replywithtunnel"] = "FakeTunnel";
        return;
    }
```

And the output from the FiddlerCore program (upon running the application):
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fc2q.png

The application is a Java application, which I had to create a keystore for using the FiddlerRoot certificate, and I am wondering if this is where the problem lies.

(Images as such since low reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: FiddlerCore uses a different SSL certificate than Fiddler itself.